# How to enable exception logging when retrying using RetryInterceptorBuilder in SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` defined like this:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(rabbitMQEventMessageConverter());
    factory.setRecoveryBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    factory.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder
            .stateless()
            .maxAttempts(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .backOffOptions(1000, 2, 5000)
            .build());
    return factory;
}
```

The problem is that if a method annotated with `@RabbitListner` throws an exception there's no logging of this exception. The method is retried though, but I'd like to see the stacktrace logged before the next retry. How can I achieve this?

Note that I'm not using Spring Boot but rather vanilla Spring 4.x (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really don’t need Spring Boot to fix the issue. You see the option is called `setAdviceChain()`. So, you really can implement a simple `MethodInterceptor` and add it to the chain after retry. In this advice you catch exception on the `invocation.proceed()`, log it and rethrow to let retry advice to do its logic.